# latex and word template for conference submission

Tags: conference, latex

I have seen in some conferences that they usually put two kinds of templates, one in Latex and the other one in word. The question that I have, and is because I will be on a conference committee in the next couple of months, is how to deal with the differences of fonts between both templates.

For what I know the Latex fonts are usually not found in Word, so how to do when one send the articles to print the proceedings. Should one person convert from Word to Latex or the Latex template should be made in a way that resembles the Word fonts?

Sort of easy question, but I have not been involved in conferences committees before.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you are asking this question because proceedings will actually be edit and printed, correct? If yes, by who? Being in a conference committee, to me, means essentially making decisions regarding the scientific content of the submissions, not wondering about typographic tweaks. If you have more technical questions regarding editing, then http://tex.stackexchange.com/ is probably the place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both LaTeX and Word support similar font packages (e.g., Times New Roman). So you could simply ask all authors to use the same font family (or set up the templates to do so).

What happens afterward depends on who's the publisher. If it's published in-house, both versions may just be published "as is." However, if an external publisher is used, both versions will likely be transferred to the publisher's "house style."

Comment: Presumably, manuscripts produced using LaTeX and Word will still differ. How is this addressed?

Answer (score 0):

IEEE provides coherent templates for office and latex available at https://m.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html

You can use them as inspiration or simply use them for your conference. I think they are free to use but you have to check.